# Encoding a CSV file using javascript and passing the value to a 2nd Cloud Page not working as expected

Tags: javascript, json, encoding, fetch

**What I am trying to do :** I have a cloud page where the user can upload CSV file. When user clicks on the “upload” button the a function called getBase64() is called (please refer the below code). The getBase64() function will encode the uploaded file and post it to a second cloud page.The second cloud page then takes the posted data.

Note: I am trying to adapt this solution to my need (csv file) by referring to this article partially https://sfmarketing.cloud/2020/02/29/create-a-cloudpages-form-with-an-image-file-upload-option/

What’s the problem : When I try to click the the “upload” button the page is not taking me to the second CloudPage. Please could anyone let me know what I am doing wrong here ?

Here is the code:

CloudPage 1

```
    <input id="file" type="file" accept=".csv">
    <br>
    <button id="button">Upload</button>
    <script runat="client">
        document.getElementById("button")
       .addEventListener("click", function() {
               var files = document.getElementById("file").files;
               if (files.length > 0) {
                   getBase64(files[0]);
               }
           });
   
       function getBase64(file) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
           reader.readAsDataURL(file);
           reader.onload = function() {
   
               //prepare data to pass to processing page 
               var fileEncoded = reader.result;
               var base64enc = fileEncoded.split(";base64,")[1];
               var fullFileName = document.getElementById("file").files[0].name;
               var fileName = fullFileName.split(".")[0];
               var assetName = fullFileName.split(".")[1];
   
               fetch("https://cloud.link.example.com/PAGE2", {  //provide URL of the processing page
                       method: "POST",
                       headers: {
                           "Content-Type": "application/json"
                       },
                       body: JSON.stringify({
                           base64enc: base64enc,
                           fileName: fileName,
                           assetName: assetName
                       })
                   })
                   .then(function(res) {
                       window.alert("Success!");
                   })
                   .catch(function(err) {
                       window.alert("Error!");
                   });
          };
           reader.onerror = function(error) {
              console.log('Error: ', error);
           };
       }
</script>
```

**CloudPage 2**

```
<script runat="server">
   var jsonData = Platform.Request.GetPostData();
   var obj = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(jsonData);
   
</script>
```

I do not see any errors in the code and when I click on the upload button I get a success message but it does not take me to the second page. Please can anyone guide me how to retrieve this posted data in second page  as I am not able to get the encoded data in page 2?

Comment: You are making a _background_ request with `fetch`, so of course that is not "taking" you anywhere (assuming by that you meant navigation of the _frontend_ to some other URL.)

Comment: thanks, I edited my question, I would like to get the posted data in page 2 but not sure how to get it using the above set-up

Comment: Also, there's really no need to base64 encode what is basically a text file. You are making your request larger like that.

Comment: The server's response will be in the `res` parameter your success callback receives.  You would have to "replace" your current page with that then (which is not a trivial task, to _replace_ a whole DOM using JavaScript.) Do you _need_ to send this as JSON? If the receiver was willing to accept a "normal" form submission, then you could do exactly that - submit a form, directly, without using fetch in the background.

Comment: The file is a csv file and I want to send it as a JSON to the second page. The second page then should be able to fetch the data from the JSON

Comment: Also, the CSV file may contain more than 50k records and i am not sure if such big data can be posted with fetch?